# font-weight bold not working with @font-face, chrome 72

Tags: css, google-chrome, font-face

In chrome 72 (mac),  the font-weight is not working, in Safari and FF the bold is displayed as expected.

```css
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Questrial';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Questrial'), local('Questrial-Regular'), url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/questrial/v8/QdVUSTchPBm7nuUeVf70viFluW44JQ.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}

p ,strong {
font-family:'Questrial';
}
```

```html
<p>normal text</p>
<strong>bold text</strong>
```

[image]

a solution to fix this, would be to download a bold font file and set it with @font-face, unfortunately in my case Questrial-Bold doesn't exists, is there another way to fix this?

Comment: seems to be fine on my chrome 72 (windows)

Comment: thanks, seems the bug is in chrome 72, (mac)

Comment: Can you check how is this codepen [https://codepen.io/prinkpan/pen/PLReVx](https://codepen.io/prinkpan/pen/PLReVx) looking at your end? @RenzoCalla

Comment: Hi the codepen is also reproducing the bug on my end..thanks btw

Comment: I have the same issue in v81 on macbook

Answer (score 0):

If you go to https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Questrial?sidebar.open=true&selection.family=Questrial you will see that **your font does not have bold option** ... But why Firefox shows bold? Good question, maybe because it is better browser?

So, choose different font family and make sure you actually include bold option by using `<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Questrial&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">` or `@font-face {  font-family: '...'; font-weight: 700; ... }`. P.s. 700 = bold.